# Github Workflow not building Rust project for i686-pc-windows-gnu target

Tags: rust, build

I have a github workflow that automates the process of building my rust app for the i686-pc-windows-gnu target, however it keeps giving me this error:

```
error: linking with `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  =
  = note: /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgpgme: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgpg-error: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lassuan: No such file or directory
          /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lgpg-error: No such file or directory
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: could not compile `todolist` due to previous error
Error: Process completed with exit code 101.
```

My project uses the [gpgme](https://github.com/gpg-rs/gpgme) Rust crate. Here is my github workflow:

```
name: Build for i686-pc-windows-gnu

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        target: [i686-pc-windows-gnu]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Install mingw-w64 toolchain
      run: sudo apt-get install -y mingw-w64
    - name: Install gpgme dependencies
      run: |
        sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
        sudo apt-get -y update
        sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
        sudo add-apt-repository universe
        sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
        sudo apt-get -y update

        sudo apt-get install -y libgpgme-dev:i386 libgpgme11-dev:i386 libassuan-dev:i386 libgpg-error-dev:i386

    - name: Set up Rust toolchain
      uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
      with:
        toolchain: stable
        override: ${{ matrix.target }}

    - name: Build project
      run: |
        rustup target add i686-pc-windows-gnu
        export PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_CROSS=1
        export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=$(rustc --print sysroot --target ${{ matrix.target }})
        export PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS=1
        export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkgconfig

        cargo build --target ${{ matrix.target }}
```

I tried checking to see if the /usr//usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu directory exists and it did.

Comment: Obviously the linker can't finish its work. What is your **specific** question? How is this related to github actions? Please remove all irrelevant tags from your question.

Comment: Why is the error showing up even though I have all the dependencies installed in my GitHub workflow

Comment: Erm, how did you verify that list of dependencies is complete? Isn't that normally done by the linker? And doesn't the linker tell a different story? Sorry to ask what might appear as the obvious here, please share more details or at least provide reference for the claims made.

Comment: And how is this problem related to contineous integration? Isn't this just a standard build problem? which build manager are you using?

Comment: With all due respect. I do not think that you have read the question even once, your uselessly trying to argue about the tag I use for my question. That could be decided later, don't you agree?. The question mentions everything. In my workflow I download all the required dependencies in the `Install gpgme dependencies` step. I also gave a link to the Rust library I was using that required me to install those dependencies. I am using the cargo build manager

Comment: Yes, that may have appeared nit-picking. Have you tried setting up the rust toolchain prior the build dependencies? And have you had this working prior creating the remote build or did you start with the remote build?

Comment: Yes I setup the rust toolchain prior to the build dependencies. The tool did compile and build for all operating systems. It was after I included the `gpgme` crate that it started to cause issues. It works fine for Linux. But since `gpgme` only supports the `i686-pc-windows-gnu` target I was forced to use that. I got it to build for Mac and Linux, its just windows and the `i686-pc-windows-gnu` target, to be more specific, where its causing errors.

Comment: Those are all three library dependencies (from four deb packages) which the mingw linker can't find you expect to be there as you install them with apt-get, right?. however if I get you right, you want to compile for windows here and the libraries installed with apt-get are for linux. Therefore my educated guess would be installing the right libraries for windows (or cross compiling them from source) - and if that is already the case - provide the right location for the linker so that it can find the libraries for windows should solve that.

Answer (score 0):

You've installed the libgpgme dependencies, but for an Ubuntu i386 architecture (i386-pc-linux-gnu), not for Windows (i686-pc-windows-gnu).  Despite being for the same architecture, you cannot use Linux shared libraries on Windows because (a) the system calls are different and (b) the object formats are different.  Linux systems use ELF executables and shared libraries and Windows uses the PE format, and unless you're using something like Wine, those won't work together.

If you want to link against the Windows versions of these libraries, you need to provide them somehow and then specify their location when linking, probably with a suitable `build.rs` file to indicate the proper arguments.  [The documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html) specifies how to do that.